# How to enable dropdown after datepicker selection made?

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have two Steps; Date is the first and Time ( `disabled` element is applied) is the seconds step. So the problem comes here, after selection of Date, should be Time is able to be select as I use code below to remove the `disabled` element. However, it does not happen. Even an alert also do not appear.

I am using Air Datepicker and selectpicker plugin on my Bootstrap 4.

**HTML**

```
<input id="date" type="text" class="form-control datepicker-here">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
    <select class="font-14 selectpicker form-control" id="time" disabled>                                               
        <option value="">-- TIME --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#date").datepicker("change",function() {
    alert("Test");
    $("#time").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: did u try `$("#date").on('change')` or `$("#date").on('blur')` ?

Comment: perfect! I have tried using `$("#date").on('change')` but does not work. However, `$("#date").on('blur')` seems work for me. Many thanks.

Comment: yes, waiting 3 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `blur` function to detect input change

```
$("#date").on('blur', () =>{
    alert("Test");
    $("#time").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```